# como guardar objetos en un array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código y no sé realmente como hacer para que cada jugador quede guardado en una lista de jugadores, osea en un `array`

Por ejemplo si quiero iterar sobre sus propios objetos, **deberé asignarle una ID a cada jugador?**  Se me ocurre que su id podría ser su indice en el `array`, pero si fuera asi, **como le asigno ID, si aún no he guardado el jugador en un array?**

```js
function Jugador(name, edad, dinero) {

  this.name = name;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.dinero = dinero;

}

function obtenerNombre() { // Obtengo el nombre del input

  var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  return obtenerN;

}

function obtenerEdad() { // Obtengo la edad del input

  var obtenerE = document.getElementById("edad").value;
  obtenerE = parseInt(obtenerE);

  return obtenerE;
}

function crearJugador() {

  var jug = new Jugador(obtenerNombre(), obtenerEdad(), 0);
  document.write(jug.name, jug.edad, jug.dinero);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Start your code here -->

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #111111;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre" />
    <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="edad" />
    <input type="button" onClick="obtenerNombre(); obtenerEdad(); crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!" />

  </form>



  <!-- End your code here -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: editado, que pavo soy xd

Comment: Los jugadores que estas creando es a nivel de cliente, para luego ser enviado a su controlador o servidor?

Comment: solo cliente @JoséMiguelSepulveda

Comment: Como recomendación simplemente. Cada vez que guardes un nuevo jugador, seria bueno que lo dejes en una localStorage almacenado. Y al abrir dicha pagina, también cargues el localStorage, ya que si por abc motivo se te cierra el navegador, no se te pierdan los datos que adquiriste. Solo es una observación :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo creando un array jugadores y calculando el id del nuevo jugador en función de los elementos ya existentes en el array.

Después de crear el nuevo jugador llamo a una función para listar todos los jugadores del array para mostrar cómo puedes recorrerlo.

EDITO. Edito el ejemplo para mostrar cómo podría modificar (añadir dinero) a un jugador en particular utilizando su id.

```js
function Jugador(id, name, edad, dinero) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.edad = edad;
  this.dinero = dinero;   
}

var jugadores = [];

function obtenerNombre() {  // Obtengo el nombre del input
  
  var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  return obtenerN;
  
}
function obtenerEdad() { // Obtengo la edad del input
  
  var obtenerE = document.getElementById("edad").value;
  obtenerE = parseInt(obtenerE);
  
  return obtenerE;
}

function crearJugador() {
  
  var jug = new Jugador(jugadores.length + 1, obtenerNombre(), obtenerEdad(), 0);
  jugadores.push(jug);
  mostrarListado();
}

function mostrarListado(){
  var lista='';
  for(var i=0; i<jugadores.length; i++){
    lista+= 'id: ' + jugadores[i].id +
      ' nombre: ' + jugadores[i].name + 
      ' edad: ' + jugadores[i].edad + 
      ' dinero: ' + jugadores[i].dinero + '\n';
  }
  document.getElementById('listado').innerText = lista;
}

function sumarDinero(){
  var dinero = parseInt(document.getElementById('dinero').value);
  var id = parseInt(document.getElementById('jugadorid').value);
  if (!(isNaN(dinero) || isNaN(id))){
    for (var i=0; i<jugadores.length; i++){
      if (jugadores[i].id==id){
        jugadores[i].dinero+= dinero;
      }
    }
    mostrarListado();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

  <style>
    body {
      
      background-color: #111111;
    }
   h1, div {
      
      color: white;
  }
   
    
  </style>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre"/>
    <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="edad"/>
    <input type="button" onClick="crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!"/>
        
  </form>
  
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="jugadorid" placeHolder="id" />
    <input type="number" id="dinero" placeHolder="dinero" />
    <input type="button" onClick="sumarDinero();" value="Sumar dinero" />
  </form>
  
  <div id="listado"></div>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yay¡ que buena me quedaron 2 dudas, supongamos que el jugador al hacer click en un boton se le sumen  $200, como hago para que sume a ese jugador con esa id y no a todos? seria como if(jug.id.indexOf(this.id) != -1)  , eso verificaria su id? y mi otra duda es poorque a la var lista la usas como acumulador

Comment: He modificado el ejemplo para poder añadir dinero a un jugador de la lista indicando su id y el dinero a añadir. No entiendo bien a qué te refieres cuando dices que uso la var lista como acumulador

Comment: La variable lista la utilizo para construir el texto a mostrar en el listado. Voy añadiendo los datos de cada jugador y finalmente establezco la cadena construida como contenido del div "listado"

Comment: si pero me refiero porqué es lista+= y no lista=

Comment: Para que en cada iteración del for se añade al contenido de la variable el texto correspondiente a los datos del siguiente jugador.
Si quitas el + se eliminaría el contenido anterior y únicamente quedaría en la variable los datos del último jugador. Así que en el listado únicamente se mostraría uno: el último. Puedes hacer la prueba modificando el código para comprobarlo.

Comment: wow asier! muchisimas gracias :) !!!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes realizar lo siguiente, acortando tu código, sólo necesitas una clase y dos funciones (de las cuales una es opcional y solo es para mostrar un resultado visual):

```js
// Declaramos un arreglo donde guardar nuestros jugadores
var misJugadores = []; 

// Obtenemos nuestro elemento donde mostrar los jugadores
var jugadores = document.getElementById('jugadores');

// Creamos una clase llamada jugador con un constructor que reciba 3 párametros
class Jugador {

  constructor(nombre, edad, dinero) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.dinero = dinero;
  }

}

// Función para crear nuestro jugador
function crearJugador() {
  // Obtenemos el nombre dado por el usuario
  var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  // Obtenemos la edad dad por el usuario y la parseamos
  var edad = parseInt(document.getElementById('edad').value)
  // Creamos nuestro jugador
  var jugador = new Jugador(nombre, edad, 0);
  // Lo añadimos a nuestro arreglo
  misJugadores.push(jugador);
  // Actualizamos nuestra tabla
  actualizarJugadores();
}

// Con esta función recorremos a todos nuestros jugadores
// en el arreglo anteriormente creado
// y los mostramos en la tabla
function actualizarJugadores() {
  // Limipamos la tabla para no repetir jugadores
  jugadores.innerHTML = ''; 
  // Recorremos nuestros jugadores
  for (var i = 0; i < misJugadores.length; i++) {
    // Añadimos nuestros jugadores a la tabla
    jugadores.innerHTML = jugadores.innerHTML +
          '<tr>' +
              '<td>' + misJugadores[i].nombre + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + misJugadores[i].edad + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + misJugadores[i].dinero + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre" />
  <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="Edad" />
  <input type="button" onClick="crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!" />
</form>
<hr />
<h1>Mis Jugadores</h1>
<button onclick="actualizarJugadores();">Actualizar jugadores</button><br /><br />
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>Edad</td>
    <td>Dinero</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="jugadores"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: como funciona lo de actualizarjugadores?

Answer (score 2):

En el siguiente ejemplo creamos un array de 1 solo elemento, el elemento tiene un índice 0 y valor 'Nombre uno':

```
var ejemplo = ["Nombre uno"];
```

En el siguiente ejemplo creamos un array asociativo (objeto) de 2 elementos; uno con índice A13 y valor 'Nombre uno' y otro con índice 10 y valor 'Nombre dos':

```
var ejemplo = {A13:"Nombre uno", 10:"Nombre dos"};
```

Después podemos usar los arrays con un for o similares:

```
for (var key in ejemplo) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

o directo:

```
console.log(ejemplo);
```

**Edit: Escrito para JS**

Comment: eso es `php`, el usuario pregunta en `javascript`

Comment: Listo, escrito para JS ahora